# Adding direct IMG links breaks template

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

So I'm editing this template to use for gallery project, but when I attempt to replace links like

```
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?tech,yet">
```

with something like

```
<img src="https://www.geoawesomeness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/earth.jpeg">
```

The picture isn't visible and and picture without direct link is displayed on top of it.

All layout just collapses. i got the template from codepen. [codepen.io/vhanla/pen/PxjZvj](https://codepen.io/vhanla/pen/PxjZvj)
Any ideas what can be causing this behavior please? thank you

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of what it looks like? Perhaps image hotlinking was blocked...

Comment: only difference in my code is: `div class="gallery-item">
                  <div class="content">
                  <a href="./pictures/torotate/DSCF0052.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src="./pictures/torotate/tn/thumbnail.png" alt="./pictures/torotate/DSCF0052.jpg" /></a></div>
            </div>`

Comment: No, can you send a screenshot of what it looks like when you use the new picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codepen seems to use dynamically resized images to mimic the [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin

https://unsplash.com/documentation#dynamically-resizable-images

> Dynamically resizable images
> Every image returned by the Unsplash API is a dynamic image URL, which means that it can be manipulated to create new transformations of the image by simply adjusting the query parameters of the image URL.
> This enables resizing, cropping, compression, and changing the format of the image in realtime client-side, without any API calls.
> Under the hood, Unsplash uses Imgix, a powerful image manipulation service to provide dynamic image URLs.

Comment: Does that mean I won't be able use that template to create gallery with photos from let's say "phone" ? Pictures that have defined dimensions?

Comment: I assume so. I did not look deeper. Use the masonry I linked instead or implement the same dynamic sizing on the server

Comment: ill give it a try. thank you